# Do you lose the increased sharpness of not having an AA filter if downscaling?

Tags: resolution, sharpness, anti-aliasing

I just read the DPreview of the Nikon 5300, and it mentions that its new 24-MP sensor doesn't have an anti-alias (AA) filter, allowing for higher sharpness.

I was wondering if you would see the sharpness difference between having the AA or not when downscaling the picture to - say - 10 MP, or does it only matter at the native resolution?

Comment: Disclaimer: the question was dictated by pure curiosity, not that I-m going to buy a new camera just for that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect of omitting the low pass filter decreases as resolution increases. That's why we're suddenly seeing AA filterless cameras, we've reached a point where aliasing is no longer a significant problem. The difference you see will depend on what glass you're using, really sharp lenses will still produce aliasing, at least in the centre.

In most cases the difference will be minor, even at full resolution, so it will be marginal at 10MP and almost certainly gone when resized further for the web.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be surprised if you saw a difference. Remember, the image has to go through a re-sizing algorithm that would cause the slight difference between an AA image and non-AA image to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I firmly believe you have more use of thorough knowledge about sharpening techniques than staring too blindly on the technical side of the camera. The idea behind the statement: I'd expect the down sampling to generate more blur than the anti aliasing filter ever did. The tool you have to recover the blur is just sharpening.